# C# windows Form help listing results from string array on to MessaeBox or new Form

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH1cu.png)

Ok i need little help with this project. This is my main windows in widows Form 
and this is code from MainForm:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestNiCat1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        private Atleticar atleticar;
        public Atleticar noviAtleticar { get { return atleticar; } }
        public string tipDiscipline;             
        private string imeDiscipline { get; set; }
        private int brojUcesnika { get; set; }
        public string [] nizUcesnika { get; set; }
        public string[] getskakac()
        {
            string[] arr = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            }
            return arr;
        }
        //listBox2.trkac to array 
        public string[] getTrkac()
        {
            string[] arr1 = new string[listBox2.Items.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                arr1[i] = listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
            }
            return arr1;
        }    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }             
        private void buttonDodaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButtonSkok.Checked)
            {              
                atleticar = new Skakac(textBoxIme.Text,textBoxPrezime.Text,float.Parse(textBoxRezultat.Text));
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(atleticar);              
            }
            else if (radioButtonPrepone.Checked)
            {
                atleticar = new Trkac(textBoxIme.Text, textBoxPrezime.Text, float.Parse(textBoxRezultat.Text));
                this.listBox2.Items.Add(atleticar);
            }                    
        }
        private void buttonTrazi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButtonSkok.Checked)
            {
                getskakac();

            }
            else if (radioButtonPrepone.Checked)
            {
                getTrkac();
            }                      
        }
    }
}
```

i have 1 abstract class and 2 classes code :

```
namespace TestNiCat1
{
    public abstract class Atleticar
    {
        protected string ime { get; set; }
        protected string prezime { get; set; }
        protected float rezultat { get; set; }        
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ime + " " + prezime + " " + rezultat;
        } }//abstract Atleticar
    public class Skakac : Atleticar
    {
        private String tip;
        public Skakac(String ime,String prezime,float rezultat)
        {
            this.rezultat = rezultat;
            this.ime = ime;
            this.prezime = prezime;
        }
    }public class Trkac : Atleticar
    {
        public Trkac(String ime,String prezime,float rezultat)
        {
            this.rezultat = rezultat;
            this.ime = ime;
            this.prezime = prezime;
        }
    }
}
```

what i need is to List all items when pressed Trazi button that will be stored into Listbox1 or listbox2 and sort them by highest result stored.
I made when i press trazi button to store all listbox items into String Array but i need help hot to sort them by highest score and show them into new messageBox OR if there is a way to sort items in listBox immidiatly as they been made in listbox by highest number.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you look for

```
public string[] getskakac()
{
    listBox1.Sorted = true;
    return listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be better off having your abstract class `Atleticar` implement an `IComparable` interface. This will make sorting much easier and give you complete control over how `Atleticar` objects are sorted.

First you need to indicate that the `Atleticar` class will implement a `CompareTo` method for sorting:

```
public abstract class Atleticar : IComparable
```

Below is the `CompareTo` method needed when you implement the `IComparable` interface. I simply compare each object based on the `rezultat` variable but you can customize this to sort on another variable(s) if needed.

```
public int CompareTo(object obj) {
  Atleticar other = (Atleticar)obj;
  if (this.rezultat == other.rezultat)
    return 0;
  if (this.rezultat > other.rezultat)
    return 1;
  else
    return -1;
}
```

Below I created a form with a `ListBox` and two buttons. One button fills the list box with some unsorted `Atleticar` objects. Button two sorts the list. I do not think you can directly sort the `listbox1.Items` so I created a list of `Atleticar` objects from the list box items and then sorted it, cleared the list box items then update it with the sorted data.

```
private List<Atleticar> GetData() {
  List<Atleticar> list = new List<Atleticar>();
  Atleticar atl = new Trkac("textBoxIme.Text1", "textBoxPrezime.Text1", 12);
  list.Add(atl);
  atl = new Trkac("textBoxIme.Text2", "textBoxPrezime.Text2", 1);
  list.Add(atl);
  atl = new Trkac("textBoxIme.Text3", "textBoxPrezime.Text3", 122);
  list.Add(atl);
  atl = new Trkac("textBoxIme.Text4", "textBoxPrezime.Text4", 99);
  list.Add(atl);
  atl = new Trkac("textBoxIme.Text5", "textBoxPrezime.Text5", 03);
  list.Add(atl);
  atl = new Trkac("textBoxIme.Text6", "textBoxPrezime.Text6", 67);
  list.Add(atl);
  atl = new Trkac("textBoxIme.Text7", "textBoxPrezime.Text7", -12);
  list.Add(atl);
  return list;
}

private void buttonGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  listBox1.Items.Clear();
  foreach (Atleticar a in GetData()) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(a);
  }
}

private void buttonSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  List<Atleticar> list = new List<Atleticar>();
  foreach (Atleticar a in listBox1.Items) {
    list.Add(a);
  }
  list.Sort();
  listBox1.Items.Clear();
  foreach (Atleticar a in list) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(a);
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense.